# React-native: Aligning TextInput inside Navigator.NavigationBar

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I've spent way too much on this so here goes another CSS question:
I would like to have a NavigationBar with a textInput Field spanning the whole bar. onFocus it switches to a Search-Component where the magic will happen. Also in the Search-Component I would like to have a "Go-Back" arrow appear on the left of the TextInput. So similar to Quora:

Switching from 
[image: search]

to this: [image]

Problem is I can't get the css right (or I think that's the problem). 
I've put together this Navigator:

```
    <Navigator
            style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{
              name: 'QuestionList',
              component: QuestionList
            }}
            renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
            navigationBar={
                            <Navigator.NavigationBar
                              style={ styles.nav }
                              sceneStyle={{marginTop:40}}
                              routeMapper={{
                                LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
                                  if(route.name == 'QuestionDetail') {
                                    return (
                                      <TouchableHighlight
                                         underlayColor="transparent"
                                         style={{ marginLeft:13,  marginTop:2}}
                                         onPress={() => { if (index > 0) { navigator.pop() } }}>
                                        <Text style={ styles.leftNavButtonText }>Back</Text>
                                      </TouchableHighlight>
                                    )}
                                    else { return null }
                                },
                                RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {

                                },
                                Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
                                  if(route.name=='QuestionDetail' || route.name=='QuestionList'){
                                  return   <TextInput
                                      style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'grey'}}
                                      onFocus={() => {navigator.push({name: Search}) }}
                                      placeholder='Ask...' />
                                  }
                                  else{return null}
                                }
                              }}
                            />
                        }
        />
```

with the stylesheet:

```
container: {
  flex:1
},
nav: {
  backgroundColor:'#e5e5e5',
  height:40,
  flex:1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'flex-start',
   shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
   shadowOpacity: 1,
   shadowRadius: 1,
   zIndex: 1,
   shadowOffset: {
     height: 1,
     width: 0,
 },
```

But I always end up with something like this (the background coloring is just to show the wrong alignment):
[image]

Thanks for your help - I'm sure it's something trivial :-/